# How could someone create a Facebook account with my email address without stealing it?

Tags: email, facebook

Someone with the same name as my sister seems to have inadvertently created a Facebook account with her email address. The funny thing is that this person doesn't seem to have ever accessed my sister's Gmail account. My sister tipped me off that emails from Facebook were appearing in her inbox. I took a look, and saw the following:

1. "Just one more step to get started on Facebook"
2. "Welcome to Facebook - get started now!"
3. "Getting back onto Facebook"

By clicking the link in one of these emails, I was able to log into the new Facebook account, and change the password.

The strange thing is, a Facebook account with an unverified email should show that yellow bar at the top of the screen, but this one didn't; yet, in the account settings, my sister's email address is listed as the primary address, but not verified.

Any ideas how this could have been done? Or if you need me to check something on the account, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that Gmail ignores dots? E.g. janesmith@gmail.com vs jane.smith@gmail.com Ref: https://jameshfisher.com/2018/04/07/the-dots-do-matter-how-to-scam-a-gmail-user/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Facebook its possible to create account with another person email, but your account still unverified until you use one of the verification methods (phone, another email).

The account can even be activated/verified if the real owner of the email address accidentally confirms by clicking on the link.

Just go to the login page, and use the password recovery facility to change the password, then log in and disable the account. Then no one can create another account with this email address.

Comment: It asks for a validation code from some unknown phone number. This answer is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the fact the facebook account could have been created there is also the posibility that the emails are phising attempts that only look like they are coming from facebook.

So do not follow links in the emails, it may not be facebook they go to.

The idea in another answer to reset the password to prevent the account from being accessible by those who created it is good, but go to facebook directly to do it. You may find out that facebook have no knowledge of the email address (a recover password mail may never appear).

If you follow a link in the mail and alter the password to your usual password, you may very well just have given phishers access to all your online logins.